# select max value from a table looking for description in another table

Tags: sql, sqlite, count, nested, max

i have 3 tables

**Buyer**

```
buyer_id | name
50       |Joe
60       |Astor
70       |Cloe
```

**Item**

```
item_id | description
1       | iphone
2       | ipod
3       | imac
```

**Item_Sold**

```
buyer_id | item_id
50       | 1
50       | 2
60       | 1
60       | 3
70       | 1
70       | 2
70       | 3
```

I want to find out the description of the best-selling item, in this case:

```
Best-Selling
iphone
```

Comment: see my edited answer...forgot FROM clause earlier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will give all item id decription whose sale is maximum i.e. when two or more item id have equal amount of sale....

```
;WITH CTE1(Id,Counts) as
(
SelectItem_Id,COUNT(buyer_id ) AS C  FROM T GROUP BY ID
) 

Select Item.Description from CTE1 A inner join 
(Select MAX(Counts) AS MaxCount FROM CTE1 ) b on a.Counts=b.MaxCount 
inner join
Item on Item.Item_Id=a.Item_Id
```

If Common table Expression Not Work you Can Try Like this....

```
Select Item.Description from (Select Item_Id,COUNT(buyer_id ) AS Counts  FROM item_sold GROUP BY Item_Id) A inner join 
(Select MAX(Counts) AS MaxCount FROM 
(
Select Item_Id,COUNT(buyer_id) AS Counts  
FROM item_sold GROUP BY Item_Id) v 
) b 
on a.Counts=b.MaxCount 
inner join
Item on Item.Item_Id=a.Item_Id
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3d6fe/13)
Here Is the Liknk of  Fiddle the case i m talknig about....it give all description who have maximun sale....
[**Case Sql Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!7/05bd7/1)

Comment: That's what i'm talking about! Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT description AS Best_Selling
FROM item
WHERE item_id = (SELECT item_id FROM( SELECT item_id ,COUNT(*) as num_items
                                      FROM Item_Sold
                                      GROUP BY item_id
                                      ORDER BY num_items DESC
                                      LIMIT 1
                                     )z
                 )
```

See **[SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/3d6fe/2)**

This answer is not totally correct . If two items have same sale amount then it will return only one of them.

Comment: You could replace the `select item_id` with a join to the `select item_id, count(*) ...`: `select i.description from item i join (select ...`

Comment: what happen if two or more item have equal amount of sale...i mean if both item id 1 and 2 have 3 buyers...it will give only first item description....

Comment: @mhasan , thank you for your help editing my question and answering it.

Answer (score 0):

```
select description as "Best-Selling" 
from (select a.item_id, b.description, count(*) count 
      from Item_Sold a,Items b
      where a.item_id = b.item_id
      group by a.item_id ) temp
where count = (select max(count) 
               from (select a.item_id, count(*) count 
                      from Item_Sold a,Items b
                      where a.item_id = b.item_id
                      group by a.item_id ) temp1)
```

Answer (score 0):

pl-sql:

```
select description as "Best-Selling"
from item
where item_id in (
    select item_id from (
        select item_id, count(item_id) as item_count 
        from item_sold 
        group by item_id) 
    where item_count = (
        select max(item_count) from (
            select item_id, count(item_id) as item_count 
            from item_sold 
            group by item_id)
        )
)
```